# DSL :: Connection top speed is ok, but acceleration is low

Tags: latency, adsl, slow-connection

My 2048 Kb/S ADSL connection downloads at the expected download speed 220 KB/s , but it takes too long to get to that speed, in other words the top speed is fine but the acceleration is terrible.
This is not a problem with large downloads because speed eventually gets to the maximum rate.
The problem is with browsing or typing through SSH, because it depends on the initial speed of the packets which could be as slow as 3 KB/s! Latency is terrible and ISP cannot understand this. Although of acceptable values for line attenuation (14.0) and SNR Margin (32.4)

No proxies used...

I cannot find similar answers on Google. Maybe I cannot descibe the problem? 
What is the term defining this problem (like Latency, Packets loss) I do not know.
And what can I tell my ISP?

EDIT:
Here is the output of `traceroute google.com`

laptop:~$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (173.194.38.102), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254)  5.538 ms  5.772 ms  12.180 ms
 2  * KHANKA-R01C-C-EG (163.121.170.229)  38.951 ms  53.544 ms
 3  host-163.121.211.134.tedata.net (163.121.211.134)  1022.649 ms  1157.199 ms  1171.533 ms
 4  host-163.121.211.134.tedata.net (163.121.211.134)  1368.481 ms  1392.954 ms  1456.449 ms
 5  host-163.121.211.125.tedata.net (163.121.211.125)  1483.733 ms  1485.976 ms  1559.233 ms
 6  10.42.0.3 (10.42.0.3)  2137.709 ms  984.750 ms  1311.599 ms
 7  10.32.8.107 (10.32.8.107)  1184.654 ms  1188.532 ms  1529.284 ms
 8  host-163.121.215.194.tedata.net (163.121.215.194)  1537.709 ms host-163.121.209.170.tedata.net   (163.121.209.170)  1525.038 ms host-163.121.215.194.tedata.net (163.121.215.194)  1784.301 ms
 9  72.14.212.13 (72.14.212.13)  1779.373 ms  1863.601 ms  2083.181 ms
10  * 209.85.252.194 (209.85.252.194)  2598.120 ms 209.85.252.36 (209.85.252.36)  2643.383 ms
11  216.239.43.42 (216.239.43.42)  2670.846 ms  2674.115 ms  3114.124 ms
12  216.239.43.4 (216.239.43.4)  2970.444 ms  2983.826 ms 216.239.46.218 (216.239.46.218)  1316.574 ms
13  209.85.249.11 (209.85.249.11)  1287.924 ms  1309.304 ms 72.14.239.93 (72.14.239.93)  1309.548 ms
14  216.239.48.69 (216.239.48.69)  1327.934 ms  1333.812 ms  1418.224 ms
15  66.249.94.24 (66.249.94.24)  1426.165 ms  1435.831 ms 66.249.94.22 (66.249.94.22)  1434.125 ms
16  72.14.239.83 (72.14.239.83)  1642.336 ms  1647.606 ms  1663.440 ms
17  64.233.174.177 (64.233.174.177)  1767.621 ms  1806.839 ms *
18  209.85.255.37 (209.85.255.37)  1554.591 ms  1483.272 ms  1498.464 ms
19  209.85.251.239 (209.85.251.239)  1301.597 ms  1308.220 ms  1319.829 ms
20  nrt19s18-in-f6.1e100.net (173.194.38.102)  1321.308 ms  1323.904 ms  1338.072 ms

Comment: What is your ping delay to some major sites ?

Comment: Google and yahoo average 1000 ms

Comment: Is this a home environment, or are you managing a company network using a DSL uplink?

Comment: I'd love to see `traceroute`s to major sites. You have a very unusual issue.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I've experienced that myself on crappy ADSL lines. So many lost or out of order packets (thanks, 200ms latency) that slow start never gets past the first few steps for smaller files.

Comment: @MarkHenderson And yet you still reached 220KB/s peak speeds? Lost packets will kill peak speeds. (I wonder if this is a missing DSL filter issue. Though if so, it's not the typical one.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - no, I never got closer than about 80% of the sync speed of the line, which I think was only 1.5Mb back then.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've edited the post to show the traceroute output

Comment: Your problem clearly comes from your 3rd hop. You can't do anything about that, except either change ISP (only good way I think) or try to convince them to fix their network. But if they didn't detected the problem themselve, this is because they are not a good provider at all.

Comment: The odd thing is, when I trace that same path (but in the other direction), I get normal pings. I see about 5ms on that hop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what host you traceroute to it? Then I can do that test from a remote SSH session.

Comment: @GregoryMOUSSAT they claims it's the local phone central office, I translate this with the above traceroute output as the 2nd node "KHANKA-R01C-C-EG"

Comment: I traced to `163.121.170.229`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information present in your question, there's really no way to help you. In fact, if that's all of the information that you've gathered, you can't even help yourself. There are three rules to troubleshooting:

1. **Gather Data**
2. **Gather Data**
3. **Gather Data**

There might be a few other rules, but they all bow in subservience to the first three. You need to be gathering as much information at the demarc point as possible. Whatever your CPE is (in your case, a DSL modem) you need to be picking as much information off of it as is possible. Poll it for SNMP information, get syslog out of it, check its manual for any special APIs, the whole nine yards.

You need to also take timed interval tests concerning latency, bandwidth, packet loss, etc. Set up SmokePing. Use a scheduled iperf script and record the pertinent information. The onus is always upon you, the customer, to prove that the ISP is the problem. You and your equipment are presumed guilty until otherwise discovered. Furthermore, the evidence that you supply to prove your innocence needs to be in triplicate with shiny graphs and perhaps intro music.

It could be as simple as some wonky congestion control ([Slow-Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) comes to mind). It could be bad lines to the DSLAM. It could be any number of things, but you can't know any of the possibilities until you've armed yourself with as much data from your end of the line as is humanly possible.

### TL;DR

Go forth and gather data.

Comment: Say "Gather data" ten times in a row and see if it doesn't sound like the weirdest thing when you're done.

Comment: +1 for gathering data. Also gather some knowledge about how the internet works: [Slow Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start) and [Why high bandwidth delay product links are slow](http://www.kth.se/polopoly_fs/1.123418!/Menu/general/column-content/attachment/lakshman-tcp.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If you have bad latency there will probably be nothing you can do for ssh since speed is typically not needed for ssh, but interactivity is.

For web browsing, if you can create an established connection to a proxy where latency isn't as bad, it may improve ( if Slow-Start is the source of the issue ). At least your connection to the proxy will as fast as it can go, and you can get all your web requests queued up on the other side.